# LINQ to Entities StringConvert(double)' cannot be translated to convert int to string

Tags: entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities, sql-server-ce-4

**Problem**

Need to convert int to string using EF4 + SQL CE4. The recommended option of using SqlFunctions.StringConvert(double) still gives me errors.

**Option 1** (original). This gives me error:

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> xxGetCustomerList()
    {
        using (DatabaseEntities db = new DatabaseEntities())
        {
            var list = from l in db.Customers
                       orderby l.CompanyName
                       select new SelectListItem { Value = l.CustomerID.ToString(), Text = l.CompanyName };
            return list.ToList();
        }
    }
```

**Option 2** (most suggested). Then as many posts suggests, I used the SqlFunctions.StringConvert() function from the library System.Data.Objects.SqlClient:

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetCustomerList()
    {
        using (DatabaseEntities db = new DatabaseEntities())
        {
            var list = from l in db.Customers
                       orderby l.CompanyName
                       select new SelectListItem { Value = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)l.CustomerID), Text = l.CompanyName };
            return list.ToList();
        }
    }
```

Which now shows below error:

```
The specified method 'System.String StringConvert(System.Nullable`1[System.Double])' on the type 'System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions' cannot be translated into a LINQ to Entities store expression.
```

**Option 3** (for very specific case). Then anoter post shows a smart solution using Dictionary, which finally works:

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> xGetCustomerList()
    {
        using (DatabaseEntities db = new DatabaseEntities())
        {
            var customers = db.Customers.ToDictionary(k => k.CustomerID, k => k.CompanyName);
            var list = from l in customers
                       orderby l.Value
                       select new SelectListItem { Value = l.Key.ToString(), Text = l.Value };
            return list.ToList();
        }
    }
```

But only work for simple pair values (key, value). Can someone help me with another solution or what I'm doing wrong with option 2?

And I hope Microsoft will soon make EF right before pushing us to move from L2S which is already stable and much more mature. I actually using EF4 just because want to use SQL CE, otherwise I stay with L2S.

Comment: Maybe is due to Im using SQL CE? instead of SQL or SQL Express? I read other post having same problem using MySQL. EF4 should be database independent, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EF is database independent at upper layers but the part dealing with conversion of linq query to SQL is always database dependent and `SqlFunctions` are dependent on SQL Server Provider but you are using SQL Server CE provider which is not able to translate functions from `SqlFunctions` class.

Btw. third option is also not a solution because it will select whole customer table to memory and use linq-to-objects after that. You should use this:

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> xxGetCustomerList()
{
    using (DatabaseEntities db = new DatabaseEntities())
    {
        // Linq to entities query
        var query = from l in db.Customers
                    orderby l.CompanyName
                    select new { l.CustomerID, l.CompanyName };

        // Result of linq to entities transformed by linq to objects
        return query.AsEnumerable()
                    .Select(x => new SelectListItem
                        {
                           Value = x.CustomerID.ToString(),
                           Test = x.CompanyName  
                        }).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: That makes sense, and I understand CE is meant for simple apps, but still, is a pain to use it this way. Thanks. I will mark your question as a solution and put my last working version.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simplified version I'm using now (specific for SQL CE):

```
    public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetBlogCategoryList()
    {
        using (SiteDataContext db = new SiteDataContext())
        {
            var list = from l in db.BlogCategories.AsEnumerable()
                       orderby l.CategoryName
                       select new SelectListItem { Value = l.CategoryID.ToString(), Text = l.CategoryName };

            return list.ToList();
        }
    }
```

Note the **db.BlogCategories.AsEnumerable()** part