# concatenate strings in LINQ query

Tags: entity-framework, linq

Suppose I want to set `FullName` property using `string.Format` like this:

```
var userList = users.Select(user => new User()
            {
                Id = user.Id,
                UserName = user.UserName,
                FirstName = user.FirstName,
                LastName = user.LastName
                FullName = string.Format("{0} {1}", user.UserName, user.FirstName)
            }).ToList();
```

This obviously doesn't work because LINQ doesn't know about `string.Format`.

My question is what are  the other options beside going over the list in memory and setting `FullName` for each item?

```
userList.ForEach(u => u.FullName = string.Format("{0} {1}", user.UserName, user.FirstName))
```

UPDATE: to see what I need, please see my conversation with @octavioccl below

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19147589/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-neither-string-format-nor-concatenation

Comment: LINQ doesn't have any issues. It's EF that complains, because `String.Format` can't be translated to SQL. You *can't* use any function that can't be translated. Why don't you simply use `+` ?

Comment: thank you, my mind is set to always use `string.Format` instead of `+` operator because in my opinion it makes concatenation more readable. but I guess this is a good exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use it:

```
FullName = user.UserName + " " + user.FirstName
```

But I think that it could be better solution (of cource if it's possible for you):

```
public class User
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string UserName {get;set;}
   public string FirstName {get;set;}
   public string LastName {get;set;}
   public string FullName
   {
      get
      {
         return string.Format("{0} {1}", FirstName, LastName);
      }
   }
}
```

then in your query build it:

```
var userList = users.Select(user => new User()
            {
                Id = user.Id,
                UserName = user.UserName,
                FirstName = user.FirstName,
                LastName = user.LastName
            }).ToList();
```

Comment: This can work in this particular scenario. Why didn't I think about it? So easy. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`String.Format` is not supported in EF, try this way:

```
FullName = user.UserName + " " + user.FirstName
```

In this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738681(v=vs.110).aspx) you will find all CLR methods that are supported

Comment: Thank you. Curious, is there a way to make this work using string.Format ? Is it possible to implement it and somehow inject it into EF, such that when EF is creating the results in memory to use it?

Comment: Yes, you can do that calling `AsEnumerable`  extension method before your `Select`. Calling that method, you are telling that you want to switch from Linq to Entities to Linq to Objects, so what you do next it would be done in memory. But be careful using `AsEnumerable` in all your DbSet, it can affect the performance of your application

Comment: Hmm, but `AsEnumerable` will return data from SQL Server in memory, so the `Select` will enumerate over an already existing collection of objects in memory.  It's exactly the scenario I want to avoid, like I said in the question I could just run `userList.ForEach(u => u.FullName = string.Format("{0} {1}", user.UserName, user.FirstName)) `. I was wondering if you can't inject right at the moment EF creates the object in memory

Comment: No, as far as I know :(. The problem is the fields you need to use come from your DbSet, if they were, eg, parameters of your query, you could apply the format that you need outside of your query and later use it inside. but not in this case

Comment: It would pretty bad if there is no other way. I think it's very important not to be forced to go over the collection in memory again just to set call some CLR methods which EF can't handle (for a good reason)

Comment: @MikeFills You are right - everything will be in memory after call to `AsEnumerable()`. Thus, you should try to narrow down the results before calling it.

Answer (score 0):

Another object is to project to an anonymous type without that property, then project to the final type in linq-to-objects:

```
var userList = users.Select(user => new {
                        Id = user.Id,
                        UserName = user.UserName,
                        FirstName = user.FirstName,
                        LastName = user.LastName
                        })
                   .AsEnumerable()
                   .Select(user => new User()
                        {
                        Id = user.Id,
                        UserName = user.UserName,
                        FirstName = user.FirstName,
                        LastName = user.LastName
                        FullName = string.Format("{0} {1}", user.UserName, user.FirstName)
                        })
                    .ToList();
```

Comment: thanks but not a good idea. you're duplicating code and iterating over an already created collection in memory