# Where clause in method syntax fails when combining strings

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda, .net-core

I am trying to retrieve a record from a database using Entity Framework and LINQ. It works mostly as expected, but for a bug with a WHERE statement I can't quite figure out.

```
var nodeId = "001";

//This works and returns the record I am looking for
var nodeDisplayName = ("#" + nodeId);
var filteredNodes = dbContext.Node.Where(n => n.DisplayName == nodeDisplayName).ToList();

//This does not work and returns 0 results
var filteredNodes2 = dbContext.Node.Where(n => n.DisplayName == ("#" + nodeId )).ToList();
```

I would expect the two variants to behave exactly the same, and they appear to do so if I run them on a List in memory. But when running against entity framework/a database they behave differently. I can fix the bug easily enough by just using the first method, but I would like to understand what causes the difference in behavior.

**EDIT**

So the generated SQL queries look like this:

```
SELECT `n`.`id`, `n`.`display_name`, `n`.`reg_tms`
FROM `tablename`.`node` AS `n`
WHERE `n`.`display_name` = '#001'

SELECT `n`.`id`, `n`.`display_name`, `n`.`reg_tms`
FROM `tablename`.`node` AS `n`
WHERE `n`.`display_name` = ('#' + '001')
```

So that clears thing up a bit. I had assumed Entity Framework would concat the strings before generating the query.

Comment: Define "behave differently". Did you examine the SQL being generated?

Comment: What is the target EF (6 or Core)? Version?

Comment: Probably you can see [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19147589/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-string-format-or-concatenation), which mentions that string concatenation (`+`) is not supported inside LINQ to Entities.

Comment: How about `$"#{nodeId}"` instead? It would avoid the ugly concat inside a nested parenthesis.

Comment: Better use [String.Equals](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.string.equals?view=netframework-4.7.2) as mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814878/c-sharp-difference-between-and-equals)

Comment: `var filteredNodes2 = dbContext.Node.Where(n => n.DisplayName == $"#{nodeId}").ToList();` use [interpolated strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) if your environment supports C# 6 or VS 2015 or above.

Comment: @KunalMukherjee Why? What does it change? Does EF even support that?

Comment: @PatrickHofman The `expression<Func<T, bool>>` which is passed in the `where()` will be eventually converted to SQL queries right?

Comment: So, does EF support `string.Format`? @KunalMukherjee

Comment: @PatrickHofman its not about EF I am just passing a regular `Func<T, bool>`  wrapped inside an expression which is valid C# code

Comment: This question *is* about EF.

Comment: @PatrickHofman So the OP can use the SQL server profiler to check the query which is generated by modifying the where with the interpolated string, whether or not it satisfies the question

Comment: @KunalMukherjee That does indeed work. Not entirely sure why, but still.

Comment: @Duckslayer because The `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` which is passed in the `where()` will be eventually converted to SQL query you can verify it in the SQL server profiler.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Confirming the interpolated string "solution". Current EF Core query translator is a "funny" thing. Would you ever think that the interpolated string (`string.Format`) or `string.Concat` (!) will be translated differently than the `string +` operator :)

Comment: @IvanStoev Oh my. Thanks for the insights!

Answer (score 3):

I am going to go ahead and work off the comments, your original question and your findings that you noted as an edit to your post --- and I think the objective was to refactor your original two statements into a single statement.

```
// code to refactor into a single statement
var nodeDisplayName = ("#" + nodeId);
var filteredNodes = dbContext.Node.Where(n => n.DisplayName == nodeDisplayName).ToList();
```

This can be refactored to...

```
// solution (refactored)
var filteredNodes = dbContext.Node.Where(n => n.DisplayName == $"#{nodeId}").ToList();
```

I had originally noted my answer as a comment, but the new syntax may not have stood out as an answer for you initially. I hope this helps.