# ASP.NET MVC: How to search decimal value?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

My table have 5 columns:

```
public partial class NPG_Chemical_DOT_and_Guide_Numbers
{
    [Key]
    [Column(TypeName = "numeric")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public decimal NPG_Chemical_DOT_and_Guide_Numbers_ID { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "numeric")]
    public decimal NPG_Chemical_ID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(64)]
    public string DOT_Number { get; set; }

    public string Guide_Number { get; set; }

    [StringLength(128)]
    public string Conditional { get; set; }
}
```

Now I can search text values in the table by using:

```
public ActionResult Index(string searchString)
    {
        var search = from m in db.NPG_Chemical_DOT_and_Guide_Numbers
                     select m;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            search = search.Where(s => s.DOT_Number.Contains(searchString) || s.Guide_Number.Contains(searchString) ||s.Conditional.Contains(searchString));
        }
        return View(search);
}
```

and:

```
<p>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<p>
    Title: @Html.TextBox("SearchString")
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</p>
}
</p>
```

The question is how to search the decimal values? I tried to use convert to string, but shown LINQ error.

Comment: What do you mean by decimal values? what's the error are you facing?

Comment: The first 2 columns are decimal type not string type, so I cannot search them by using: if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
{ search = search.Where(s=>s.DOT_Number.Contains(searchString))  }

Comment: Possible duplicate of [search decimal values in Linq query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29622158/search-decimal-values-in-linq-query)

Comment: Layla, You can have a look on the answer posted by @YazanAti or another I've provided in above comment, let us know if these answers doesn't work for you.

Comment: What EF version are you targeting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `SqlFunctions.StringConvert`. There is no overload for int so you need to cast to a double or a decimal. Your code ends up looking like this:

```
var items = from c in contacts
            select new ListItem
            {
                Value = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)c.ContactId).Trim(),
                Text = c.Name
            };
```

Comment: How to do multiple values? and what should I change in: if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))?

Answer (score 0):

try this solution

```
String SearchWord = "500.4";    
decimal searchBy; //define a decimal variable to hold the Search By value
decimal.TryParse(SearchData, out searchBy); //try parse it to decimal from string
```

And in your query do this:

```
Employees = _entities.Employees.Where(p.Salary==searchBy)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Exactly as searching a string but with some changes:

```
public ActionResult Index(string searchString){
    searchString = searchString.Replace(',', '.');

    var search = from m in db.NPG_Chemical_DOT_and_Guide_Numbers
                 select m;

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString)){
        search = search.Where(s => (s.DOT_Number.ToString()).Contains(searchString)
                 || (s.Guide_Number.ToString()).Contains(searchString)
                 || s.Conditional.Contains(searchString));
    }
    return View(search);
}
```

With this code line:
`(s.DOT_Number.ToString()).Contains(searchString)`
you can search the column, but the notation `.` instead of `,`

The **Replace** function above is resposible for comfortable search without noticing the change between `,` and `.`

so you can search with notation `,` without noticing that the program replacing it in background (user-friendly version)

I hope it helped!